# How to build one file contains other files, selected by mask?

Tags: linux, shell

I need to put the contents of all *.as files in some specified folder into one big file.

How can I do it in Linux shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need all files in all subdirectories, th most robust way to do this is:

```
rm onebigfile
find -name '*.as' -print0 | xargs -0 cat >> onebigfile
```

This:

- deletes onebigfile
- for each file found, appends it onto onebigfile (this is why we delete it in the previous step -- otherwise you could end up tacking onto some existing file.)

A less robust but simpler solution:

```
cat `find -name '*.as'` > onebigfile
```

(The latter version doesn't handle very large numbers of files or files with weird filenames so well.)

Answer (score 6):

You mean `cat *.as > onebigfile`?

Comment: Thx. Great. And how can I find files in all sub-folders?

Comment: @Max: In zsh and Bash 4, `cat **/*.as > onebigfile` will do.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you mean by compile but are you looking for [tar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar)?